# Azure Media Services V3 audio analyzer transcript 10 minute limit

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services, audio-analysis

I have a project that uses **Azure Media Services** to broadcast video streams and when 
 a broadcast ends it feeds the generated **Asset** to a **Job** to extract insights from it.

The problem is that it generates all the insights data perfectly but the Transcription (speech-to-text) works only for 10 minutes.

I can see thumbnails analyzed at 30 minutes into the video:

```
{
                    "id": "509c12e0-e6b8-4e09-bd6a-6ddb4f12417a",
                    "fileName": "FaceInstanceThumbnail_509c12e0-e6b8-4e09-bd6a-6ddb4f12417a.jpg",
                    "instances": [
                        {
                            "adjustedStart": "0:37:32.831",
                            "adjustedEnd": "0:37:32.864",
                            "start": "0:37:32.831",
                            "end": "0:37:32.864"
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

but the transcript always stops generating data at the 10 min mark

```
{
            "id": 83,
            "text": "Many things are also to do you Bonnie?",
            "confidence": 0.8468,
            "speakerId": 3,
            "language": "en-US",
            "instances": [
                {
                    "adjustedStart": "0:09:55.36",
                    "adjustedEnd": "0:09:58.39",
                    "start": "0:09:55.36",
                    "end": "0:09:58.39"
                }
            ]
        }
```

The broadcast displays correctly in the AMS Player that I have embedded in my site and if I download the broadcast files and upload it to **videoindexer.ai** using a trial account it generates the transcript OK for the whole video.

The **Video Indexer** option is there but I would like to avoid having to link another service and API into the app so any help overcoming the 10 minute limit is welcome.

Comment: There is no 10 minute limit of any sort. Something else going on. 
File a support ticket with a sample that repros the issue.

Comment: @johndeu We're trying to open a ticket with our cloud provider, I removed the "arbitrary limit" phrase to avoid confusion if other users read the question.

Answer (score 0):

could you please file a support ticket on this through the Azure Portal.  That way we can track it down. You will want to upload a sample file in the support ticket as well.